# convert JSON input to form-data in AWS application gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Our old legacy APIs accept the data only in form-data format, but I am required to send my data as JSON in body of request. So, how I can convert my JSON (`application/json`) input to form data in **AWS Application gateaway**.

I have input parameter like this

`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}`

[image: Method Request Page]

[image: Integration Request Page]

I tried many solution with template mapping and query string parameter but they didn't work for me maybe I am doing something wrong. Above configuration is fully supporting form-data.

**Note**: *Due to some reason I don't want to change my legacy django code to handle JSON input instead of form data.*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the structure of a raw POST form-data request. Then you should be able to structure the Integration Request to fit the form-data format using the right Content-Type and mapping template.

There is an example for GET and an example for POST on this page (with the caption "the HTTP request looks like this") https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data